# Swift linker error when accessing @NSManaged properties of a final class

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

I'm having issues in a larger project, and boiled it down to this simple code. For demo purposes, I have created a new Swift project with the following in a Model.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class A: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var foo: String
}

final class B: A {
    @NSManaged var bar: String
}

func testB(obj: B) -> String {
    return "\(obj.foo) \(obj.bar)"
}
```

This compiles, but the linker complains about accessing `bar`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__TFC21TestFinalManagedClass1Bg3barSS", referenced from:
      __TF21TestFinalManagedClass5testBFCS_1BSS in Model.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The combination of an `@NSManaged var` in a `final class` seems to be what causes the error. (The class inheritance from `A` is included to demonstrate that the `foo` property is accessible on an object of type `B`, but not the `bar` property.)

I am using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d).

Is there some rule hidden in the documentation about marking an `NSManagedObject` subclass as final? Or is this just a bug in the compiler/linker?

Comment: I am having this same issue -- only when I upgraded to Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in Xcode 6.3 beta.